# D3 Wordwrap with data-driven width limit

Tags: javascript, text, d3.js

It's fairly straightforward to create some text in D3 and have it wordwrap:

```
var textElement = svg.selectAll('text')
                   .data(myData)
                   .enter()
                   .append('text')
                   .text(someVeryLongText)
                   .call(wrapText, allowedWidth);
```

The wrapText() function is implemented using one of the fairly standard examples out there (e.g. http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321).

The problem I have is when I want to make the allowable width for each text field dependent upon upon the datum, something like:

```
                   ...
                   .text(someVeryLongText)
                   .call(wrapText, function(d) {
                     return d.someCondition ? 100 : 200;
                   });
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust the wrap function in the example you linked as indicated below and use the desired call signature in your post.  Working example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/cool-Blue/418d3f6d91915602e4fd).

```
function wrap(text, width) {
    text.each(function(d, i/*[edit]*/) {
        var text = d3.select(this),
            words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
            word,
            line = [],
            lineNumber = 0,
            lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
            y = text.attr("y"),
            dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
            tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em"),
            //[edit]add dWidth
            dWidth = typeof width === "function" ? width(d, i) : width;
        while (word = words.pop()) {
            line.push(word);
            tspan.text(line.join(" "));
            if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > dWidth/*[edit]*/) {
                line.pop();
                tspan.text(line.join(" "));
                line = [word];
                tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Just bear in mind that, in its current form it will break if there are already  tspan elements. But if you tweak it slightly, it's easy to fix.